# Recording script using parec records fine in the foreground, but records silence when launched from crontab

Tags: pulseaudio, cron, mp3, audio-recording

I have a script that uses pactl and parec to record audio from a browser that is streaming a radio station. Sox is then used to compress the captured audio to mp3. It records fine when run in the foreground but records silence when launched from a crontab job.

Here are the key lines of the recording script:

```sh
# Get sink monitor:
MONITOR=$(pactl list | grep -A2 '^Source #' | grep 'Name: .*\.monitor$' | awk '{
print $NF}' | tail -n1)

# Record it raw, and convert to whatever
cmd="timeout ${TIMESECS}s parec -d \"$MONITOR\" | sox -t raw -r 44100 -sLb 16 -c
 2 - \"$TEMPFILE\""
echo $cmd
eval $cmd
```

Why would the script work in the foreground but not when launched from crontab?

Comment: In order to debug, you could record the full output of the script to a log file like this (cron line) `* * * * * /path/to/script.sh > /path/to/log.$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).log 2>&1`

Comment: @bistoco Yes, I already tried that. I added echo statements that dumped the MONITOR and TEMPFILE. The values where identical in foreground and from the crontab job.

Comment: did you noticed the `2>&1` at the end?, it will also redirect errors to your log file if any.

Comment: @AndrewS. any update on a solution or even a workaround? I am having the same issue with the same behavior. I am not tied to using crontab, but it seemed like the most logical solution. Any updates would be appreciated!